# Best way to construct C# Type out of a string for serialization/deserialization

Tags: .net, caching, serialization, reflection, redis

I want to convert a string into a C# type.   The use-case here is I am storing serialized data in a cache along with a type and then casting it back.
I have a custom class called DataEntities.Show (where DataEntities is a namespace).
If I store that class' type "DataEntities.ShowEntity" and then try to deserialize it, all is good and dandy.

Troubles begin when I store object of type List in the cache.
Its resulting type is "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DataEntities.ShowEntity]" so the lookup below fails since assembly contains only DataEntities.ShowEntity and the resultant type isn't found.    I get a null as a result.

I can think of an ugly solution where I parse a string type for prefix of "List" or "Enumeration" but there has to be a more elegant way of doing it. Any advice?

```
    private static Type GetGlobalType(string s)
    {
        Type t = null;
        Assembly[] av = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        foreach (Assembly a in av)
        {
            Type[] types = a.GetTypes();
             t = Type.GetType(s + "," + a.GetName());
             if (t == null)
             {
                  t = Type.GetType(s);
             }

             if (t != null)
                  break;
        }
        return t;
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to use JSON or XML at all? Both methods will allow you to use built-in C# methods for bost serialisation and de-serialisation.

Comment: Did you try [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text)?

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason why you are handling the casting on your own.  You can use implicit declaration to handle this using simple XML serialization.

When the class is deserialized it will automatically set the correct type at run-time, no need for casting.

```
        var dataIn = new List<DataEntities.ShowEntity>();            
        Console.WriteLine("Type before serialization: " + dataIn.GetType());

        var xs = new XmlSerializer(dataIn.GetType());            
        var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\test.xml");
        xs.Serialize(xmlWriter, dataIn);
        xmlWriter.Close();

        var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\test.xml");
        var dataOut = xs.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        xmlReader.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("Type after deserialization: " + dataOut.GetType());
```